# How to properly add celery in a two flask app setup

Tags: flask, docker-compose, redis, celery

I'm trying to understand how to configure celery and flask and how both work together. I have a docker compose with for services: two flask applications that communicate with each other, redis and the celery worker.

The flask app that runs celery calls a couple of functions after creating the flask app. What I don't get is why the celery worker also run those functions (or so it seems so considering the output).

So, here is my docker compose file:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  events:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: events.Dockerfile
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: run_events
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    #command: ls -r /app
    command: flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8001
    ports:
      - 8001:8001  
  celery_worker:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: bpa.Dockerfile
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: run_bpa
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: celery -A run_bpa.celery worker --loglevel=INFO
    user: nobody
    depends_on:
      - redis     
      - events 
  bpa:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: bpa.Dockerfile
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: run_bpa
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - events
```

I'm a bit lost here, I expected that bpa flask would run normally whereas the celery worker would just be there waiting for celery task to arrive. However, the output of bpa and celery_worker looks the same at the beginning. If I just comment all bpa service, then the celery_worker seems to do both jobs. What is the correct way of running this then? Having both the flask app and the celery worker together seems against the point. Should I create a new flask app for the worker and then somehow include the modules where the celery tasks from the other two flask apps are so that bpa and celery worker run independently?